# How to check the value belongs to an interval in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I define what elements of an array are in a range.
For example:
a = [2.3, 3.6, 5.1, 3.8]
I want to select the elements between 3 and 4 without loop, like this:
a is in [3,4]
or
a>3 && a<<4
Thank you.

Comment: Also, have a look through the [find](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) documentation.

Comment: Using `find` to select out elements in this context is debatable.  It's better to use logical indexing.... but if you want to determine **where** those elements are, then yes `find` is what you need.

Comment: @rayryeng agreed, but for the beginning matlab user, `find` is a useful one to know in this context.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty easy:

```
>> a = [2.3 3.6 5.1 3.8]; %// Define your data
>> b = a(a > 3 & a < 4)

b =

    3.6000    3.8000
```

However, if it is your goal to determine **which** elements are between 3 and 4, you can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as what Maurits said in the comment above:

```
>> f = find(a > 3 & a < 4)

f = 

    2     4
```

Logical indexing with MATLAB will be one of your best friends in your MATLAB learning journey.  Read this post by Steve Eddins from MATLAB for some tips: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/

Comment: Minor correction: Steve Eddins, not Loren Shure :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I thought i read Loren Shure lol. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to the logical indexing approach if you are interested in the position of the elements inside array "a" is using `find()`

```
a = [2.3 3.6 5.1 3.8];
b = find(a > 3 & a < 4);
b =

2    4
```

Just wanted to add this for completeness in case you were were looking for the indices of a that corresponded to your particular case. Otherwise rayryeng's method is the way to go!